# Two mobile apps have same function/near identical names - copyright trouble?

Tags: copyright

I'm developing a mobile app and recently discovered that another app was published to the iOS App Store in 2011 with a similar name and almost identical function.  Should I anticipate copyright trouble by releasing my app?

Comment: Probably not copyright trouble, but possibly trademark trouble.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  What is the best way to proceed then?

Comment: The easiest solution is to change the name of your app.  Otherwise you have to assess the other developer's capacity to make your life difficult, and decide whether you want to risk that possibility.

Comment: In the case of the App Store, where Apple can reject your application for practically any reason, you can expect that your app will just be rejected by Apple. Choose a name that isn't similar.

Comment: In this case, the name is the lesser of my worries and can be easily changed.  My greatest concern is the similar functionality of the two apps.  When I began, I believed my idea to be unique but have found that is not the case.  Is that reason alone to not proceed?

Comment: Regarding the idea: This can be business trouble, but if you came up with it on your own, it should not be legal trouble. The only thing I could imagine is a patent, maybe somebody from a jurisdiction that has software patents can elaborate on that (in my country, it's not possible to patent software functionality).

Comment: It's not possible to prevent others from making applications that do the same thing.  It's even true of machines.  A patent only protects the specific mechanism of doing something.  Imagine if the first company that invented word processing software had been able to prevent everyone else from making word processing software.  The world would be a very different place.